# Xamarin Forms - iOS Deployment stopped working

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I've been using Visual Studio 2019's Xamarin Hot Restart to deploy iOS applications from Visual Studio (on windows) to an iPad.

Our company recently switched emails, so my account got a new email with the apple developer accounts.
I appear to have the same admin privileges as before.

I'm using automatic provisioning with the developer team selected.

Since I switched my apple account to the new apple account, whenever I deploy the app to iPad, the app opens and immediately closes. What other settings do I need to set?

Comment: It sounds like your app is crashing. What does the output window of Visual Studio have to say? You might also want to try to deploy a sample app via XCode to your iPad

Comment: The 'Connecting Debugger' pops up. IT says 'Please launch the application on the device. I launch the application on the device and it immediately closes The build output has no information after the application failed to open automatically. It told me to open the application and that's it.

Comment: The whole workflow in not familiar to me. I would expect the debugger to start the application for you. Can you build a sample app via XCode and deploy it through XCode?

Comment: I have no experience in xcode usage.

Comment: Hi, do you use new Apple account to check [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#initial-setup)?